# "base.send :include, InstanceMethods" ---> What does this do?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at a module X which contains two modules called "`InstanceMethods`" and "`ClassMethods`".

The last definition in module X is this:

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    base.send :extend,  ClassMethods
  end
```

What does this do?

Comment: I know it's not your code, but note that there is no need to have a InstanceMethod module: the parent module is already being included, so we should put the instance methods there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`included` gets called whenever a module is included into another module or class. In this case it will try to invoke `base`'s `include` method to get the module methods, variables and constants from `InstanceMethods` added into `base` and then will try to invoke `base`'s `extend` method to get the instance methods from `ClassMethods` added to `base`.

It could also have been

```
def self.included( base )
  base.include( InstanceMethods )
  base.extend( ClassMethods )
end
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. There's a class W that is including module X, so the idea is that W gets all of the instance methods and class methods contained in X through these modules. The missing piece was how 'included' gets called - but you're saying as soon as I say "W include X", the included() method will be called. – franz 0 secs ago

Comment: That's right. There's some more information and a friendly example at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001683

Comment: include is a private method of the Method class. thus, base.include will not work.

Answer (score 2):

'send' invokes its first argument as a method on the object its called on, and the rest of the arguments are sent as arguments to the method. So in this case,

```
base.send :include, InstanceMethods
```

is equivalent to

```
base.include(InstanceMethods)
```

Which adds the methods in the InstanceMethods module to the 'base' object

Comment: It's not quite equivalent, as `base.send :include` will still call include even if the method has been made private. `base.include` will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's defining a class method which takes a parameter "`base`". It then calls the `include` and `extend` methods on `base`, passing the module `InstanceMethods` and `ClassMethods` as arguments, respectively. The call to `include` will add the instance methods defined in `InstanceMethods` to `base`. I'm not familiar with the `extend` method, but I assume it will do something like that too, but for class methods.